# Drawing two balls from two urns

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Assume that there are two urns. The first urn contains 4 red balls, 3 blue balls, and 3 white balls. The second urn contains 2 red balls, 4 blue balls, and 4 white balls. You randomly select an urn and take two balls from the urn. The probability that you pick the first urn is 40%. What is the probability that 
(a) the two balls are red? 
(b) the second ball is blue? 
(c) the second ball is blue given that the first ball is red?

**My attempt:**

U1 = first urn, U2, = second urn, R,B,W = red, blue, white respectively 
 
**(a)** P(R,R) = P(first ball R) * P(second ball R) 
$P$(first ball R) = $P(R|U1)P(U1) + P(R|U2)P(U2)$ = $(\frac{4}{10})(\frac{4}{10}) + (\frac{2}{10})(\frac{6}{10}) = \frac{28}{100}$

For the second ball, we know that a red ball has already been drawn, so we need to take into account two possibilities: first ball was drawn from urn 1 and first ball was drawn from urn 2 
 
if first ball was from U1: $P$(second ball R) = ($\frac{3}{9}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{2}{10}$)($\frac{6}{10}$) $= 0.253333$ 
if first ball was from U2: $P$(second ball R) = ($\frac{4}{10}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{1}{9}$)($\frac{6}{10}$) $= 0.22667$ 
Therefore, $P$(second ball R) = $0.253333 + 0.22667 = 0.48$

Final answer: $P(R,R) = (0.28)(0.48) = 0.1344$

**(b)** $P$(second ball B)$ = P(R,B) + P(W,B) + P(B,B)$ 
 
$P(R,B) = P$(first R) * $P$(second B) 
We know that P(first R) = 0.28. For the second ball B, we split it into two cases: when the first ball drawn from the first urn, and drawn from the second urn. 
 
if first ball from U1: $P$(second ball B) = ($\frac{3}{9}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{4}{10}$)($\frac{6}{10}$)
if first ball from U2: $P$(second ball B) = ($\frac{3}{10}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{4}{9}$)($\frac{6}{10}$) 
$P$(second ball B) $= 0.733333$ so $P(R,B) = (0.28)(0.733333) = 0.205333333$

$P(W,B) = P$(first W) * $P$(second B) 
$P$(first ball W) = $P(W|U1)P(U1) + P(W|U2)P(U2)$ = $(\frac{3}{10})(\frac{4}{10}) + (\frac{4}{10})(\frac{6}{10}) = \frac{36}{100}$  
For the second ball B, we split it into two cases: when the first ball drawn from the first urn, and drawn from the second urn. 
 
if first ball from U1: $P$(second ball B) = ($\frac{3}{9}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{4}{10}$)($\frac{6}{10}$)
if first ball from U2: $P$(second ball B) = ($\frac{3}{10}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{4}{9}$)($\frac{6}{10}$) 
$P$(second ball B) $= 0.733333$ so $P(W,B) = (0.36)(0.733333) = 0.264$

$P(B,B) = P$(first B) * $P$(second B) 
$P$(first ball B) = $P(B|U1)P(U1) + P(B|U2)P(U2)$ = $(\frac{3}{10})(\frac{4}{10}) + (\frac{4}{10})(\frac{6}{10}) = \frac{36}{100}$  
For the second ball B, we split it into two cases: when the first ball drawn from the first urn, and drawn from the second urn. 
 
if first ball from U1: $P$(second ball B) = ($\frac{2}{9}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{4}{10}$)($\frac{6}{10}$)
if first ball from U2: $P$(second ball B) = ($\frac{3}{10}$)($\frac{4}{10}$) + ($\frac{3}{9}$)($\frac{6}{10}$) 
$P$(second ball B) $= 0.0.6488888$ so $P(W,B) = (0.36)(0.0.648888) = 0.2336$

Therefore, $P$(second ball B) $= 0.7029333333$

**(c)** $P(R,B) = 0.205333333$ from part (b)

Could someone check and see if I did this correctly? I feel like I may have overcounted things since there are so many scenarios. Thank you

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** It's healthier if you condition on the chosen urn:
$$\begin{align}P(RR)&=P(RR|U_1)P(U_1)+P(RR|U_2)P(U_2)\\ &= \frac{4}{10}.\frac{3}{9}.\frac{4}{10}+\frac{2}{10}.\frac{1}{9}.\frac{6}{10}=\frac{1}{15}\end{align}$$
Your answer differs from this one, because you still consider the choice of urns in the second draw. I haven't calculated (b) and (c), however since they follow a similar approach, I don't think you got the right answer for them. Apply the above logic to (b) and (c). Also, in (c), it asks for $P(B_2|R_1)$; you seem to calculate a joint probability; not a conditional one.

Comment: thank you. For part (b) I calculated P(RB) + P(WB) + P(BB) using the same logic as that you gave. For part (c), would I do P(B2|R1) = P(RB) / P(R) and use P(RB) from (b) and calculate P(R) as 0.28, which I did in my original answer?

Comment: @IrCa Yes, you can do that, your P(R) calculation is correct.